# Show the display of one local webpage on another local webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm streaming video from a raspberry pi 3 using this demo:
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/
It generates a streaming video at my localhost:8081

I want to put this video on another webpage where I can control a remote control car using the video that I'll be streaming from the front of the car, is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the html look like on the 8081 page? I'd imagine that contains a <embed>, or <object>, or some other tag that actually contains and renders the actual video.  Can you just copy that code to a new page and edit the html to include your controls?

Comment: @JustinHeath I'm not sure where or what the html says, I didn't save an html page and viewing the page source doesn't do anything.

Unfortunately, an iframe is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use an iframe. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not loading my page

Comment: Hmm, check the console, are there any errors? Also copy/paste all of your html into https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to make sure there aren't any html errors

Comment: No errors on the console i used to start my node service or in the webpage.

I cannot see the html for the video stream webpage, it's not generated anywhere I can see and I can't view the source for the webpage

Comment: Ok, but you can see the video stream, correct? In google chrome right click in the whitespace of the page that has your stream; hopefully you will see "View page source" http://kyakaisekare.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/view-source-chrome.jpg  Click "View page source" and add the html source to your original question. I'll comment back on your original question to make this easier

Comment: I was able to get to "inspect element" by this method and copy a line from it! thanks!

Comment: Cool, if iframe works, please re-accept my answer :) If you can't get it working let me know. One thing to note, if you want to be able to use a real website (one not in your local network) to view the video, you'll need to follow the steps near the bottom of the tutorial you linked to. Then use iframe like this: `<iframe src="192.168.1.103:8081"></iframe>`